# How do I get onto the left rock spire as I slide down the eastern side of Elden Volcano?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

As I slide down the eastern side of Elden Volcano, I've been trying and trying and trying to hit the air geyser in front of the left rock spire (circled in red) and never come close:

[image]

I've tried exiting the tunnel above from the left and right sides, and the middle.  No trajectory gets me even close.  **How do I slide into the geyser in front of this spire?**  My hearts are getting dangerously low from continuously traveling through the lava room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're trying to get to the circled part or the part near the pointer?

There's no trick to reaching that spot, just slide in that direction and you should be able to reach the vent normally.

If in doubt, you may still *run* through the slopes as long as you are on your own two feet.  If you're sliding, then well, you won't be able to get up and run until you hit level ground.  If you *can* get to the other set of rocks on the other side, you can jump off and sprint toward the vent.  But like I said, you don't really need to do anything special as you should have been able to reach it normally.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify that  trying to get to the spire circled red in the image.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you were going for the circled part.

Comment: I was never able to slide near the left-side rock.  The closest I ever got was the middle rocks.  I ended up steering toward the right-hand spire, and after getting blown to the top, jumping down and sprinting to the left spire.

Answer (score 0):

When you slide down something, try to just tilt your nunchuck left and right to get on to something. Like for example, one if the tears in Dins Silent Realm.:)